# Avoid scroll up when table remove rows

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, scroll, html-table

I have a table with 18 table rows that is filled by ajax request.

When I click on the next page button, I remove all existing rows from the table then fill this table with 18 next rows. The table is at the end of the body.

My ajax success handler is :

```
$('#commandeTable  > tbody tr').remove();
$.each(data.commandeList, function () {
$("#commandeTable > tbody").append($("<tr>blabla</tr>").hide().fadeIn(500));
})
```

My problem is because the table is empty before I fill it again, the scrollbar go to top of the page. How can I avoid this?

Comment: you dont need to remove them, just use an ajax request with fetching the data and set a Limit with start and end. first page would be 1 - 18 results, 2nd page 19 - 36 results etc

Comment: @SC92 can you be more explicit ? I already use an ajax request with 'pageindex' and 'pagesize' arguments. The server response contains 18 object that I put in the table. But I have to remove the rows from the previous ajax request before adding theses new rows

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found the solution :

It is not because of the empty table. I have to put e.preventDefault(); in the next page button click handler